# Как найти кол-во вхождений в строке?

Tags: delphi

есть в переменной page HTML код страницы
мне нужно найти сколько раз в нём встречается такой текст:

```
 http://сайт/projects/project
```

я точно знаю что он этот текст встречается 2 раза но при использовании такого кода выдаёт почему то 0

```
   n:=0;
  for i := 1 to Length(page) do
 if page[i] = 'http://сайт/projects/project' then
 inc(Result);
 memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr(n));
```

Что я делаю не так? как её можно найти?

Comment: ЛОЛ. "Прежде чем писать код, обдумайте все, как следует"...

Comment: Хмм... на сколько помнится мне в одинарные кавычки заключается символ и не больше. При заключении в кавычки более 1 символа (за исключением интерпретаций кодов, например, #13) компилятор выдаст ошибку. Следовательно делаю вывод - как вы вообще 0 получили, если эти строчки не должны скомпилироваться вовсе?

Comment: скомпилируеться без проблем возможно варинг вылезет, но условие срабатывать не будет.

Comment: Вы путаете с C. В делфях одинарными кавычками вполне можно выразить строку. По-крайней мере в Borland Delphi 7.
А вот сравнивать char с длинной строкой — это да, сложно

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы сравниваете 1 символ со строкой, естественно условие никогда не выполняется.

Answer (score 2):

даже если будете сравнивать всю строку **page** и он будет равной 'http://сайт/projects/project'... мемо все равно выведет 0... так как в этом участке кода не видно какое либо изменение переменной **n**

Comment: а причем здесь **n** ? При выполнении условия инкриминируется переменная **Result**

Comment: @savro, ну да, а выводится-то *n*.

Comment: "я точно знаю что он этот текст встречается 2 раза но при использовании такого кода выдаёт почему то 0"

судя по куску кода, который предложил автор вопроса, можно предположить что результат выводится в мемо... иначе зачем он показал строки "n:=0;" и "memo1.Lines.Add(inttostr(n));"  ??

p.s. наличие переменной result не говорит о том что "дело происходит" в функции